# A log cut off function

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes

Let $\Omega$ denote a bounded smooth domain in $R^N$ and consider $\Gamma$ a smooth subset (assume its some $k$ dimensional manifold where $k \le N-1$).    Let $ \delta(x)=dist(x, \Gamma)$.    On occasion you might have some pde that holds on $\Omega \backslash \Gamma$ and you want to prove by a density argument some result.

For instance suppose we have $ \Delta w(x)= 0 $ in $ \Omega \backslash \Gamma$  with $ w=0$ on $ \partial \Omega$  and we have $ w$ is bounded and we would like to show that $ w=0$.    If $dim(\Gamma)<N-2$  then we can prove this by multiplying the pde by $ \gamma_{\epsilon}^2 w(x)$ where $ \gamma_\epsilon$ is a cut-off which is zero near $\Gamma$.   We can use
$$ \gamma_\epsilon(x)= \frac{\delta(x)-\epsilon}{\epsilon}$$ for $ \{x: \epsilon <\delta(x)<2 \epsilon\}$ and extend in the obvious way outside this set.

If $ dim(\Gamma)=N-2$ then this method fails.  I recall there is a smarter way to pick the cut off (that might involve two parameters and a log) that allows one to still handle this higher dimensional case.    Any comments would be appreciated.
thanks

Comment: The key word to search for when looking for these excision-type arguments is 'capacity'. Evans and Gariepy have a nice argument for this in their book; in my edition this is Theorem 3 in Section 4.7.2 'Capacity and Hausdorff dimension'. If you specifically want to use log cut-off functions, I believe you could use a (suitably modified) version of what Colding and Minicozzi do in their book. (Search for 'logarithmic cutoff' in the index.)

Comment: thank you very much for your comment. I will take a look at the references you suggest.